# How to remove key/value from JSONB column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I want to write a simple update statement to remove a key/value from a jsonb column or even just set the value to null.

This doesn't work as I had hoped.

```
UPDATE mytable SET params->>'mykey' = NULL WHERE id = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `-` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to remove an attribute from a jsonb object:

```
update mytable set params = params - 'mykey' where id = 1234
```

Or you can set the value of a given key to `null` with `json_set()`:

```
update mytable set params = json_set(params, '{0, 'mykey'}', null) where id = 1234
```

Comment: What does the `{0, 'mykey'}` syntax mean?

Comment: @Catfish:  `{0, 'mykey'}` represents the path to the key that you want to modify.

Comment: `0` meaning it's at the root level of the object?

Comment: @Catfish: yes, that's it.